# В обычном input type='radio' как обеспечить вывод кружочка строго слева от input при сжатии окна браузера?

Tags: html, input

Выводит так:
[image]

А хотелось бы так:
[image]

Никаких лишних пробелов между input и текстом разумеется нет:

```
<input type='radio'/>Скорее&nbsp;не&nbsp;сбылось
```

Comment: Если браузер перенёс так, как перенёс, то это означает, что для кружочка там физически нет места и что вы хотите невозможного

Comment: Неужели нет никакого простого решения? :(

Comment: А что вы ожидаете увидеть, когда кружочек и текст физически не могут поместиться в одну строку?

Comment: Вопрос решился. Отказался от Bootstrap-верстки, сильно косячной. И воспользовался Flexbox. Кружок сразу стал на место. Т.е. браузер теперь не пытается переносить текст внутри блока, а переносит его целиком на новый ряд, если окно его поджимает.